# How do I query a WhereChain in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, where-clause, ruby-on-rails-6

I’m upgrading from Rails 4.2 to Rails 6.  I have this scope in a model …

```
  scope :valid_type, -> { where{ (model_type == nil) | (modeltype << [36, 38]) } }
```

Previously, I could run this

```
MyModel.valid_type.include?(model_instance)
```

But now I get

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `include?' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x00007fb9fc58b3e0>
```

What’s the right way in Rails 6 to check for inclusion in a WhereChain?

Comment: I don't think you want a WhereChain object. I think you're getting one b/c of a strange conditions syntax. You are doing a bitwise 'OR' of a boolean (`model_type == nil`) and perhaps an array `modeltype << [36,38]`. What is your intent?

Comment: I think if I'm able to write the scope in terms or a conditional (is model_type nil or does it belong to an array of values) then I should be good.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently passing a block to `where`. `where` does not accept a block neither in [4.2](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where) or [6.0](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where)

The block parameter is being ignored. Since you're not passing an argument to `where`, it's being treated as a `WhereChain` [that only has one method on it](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain): `not`. For example as a part of `where.not(my_column: nil)`

You'll need to fix your syntax. Use the `.or` method to join your queries and use proper `ActiveRecord` syntax.

```rb
scope :valid_type, -> { where(model_type: nil).or(where(modeltype: [36, 38])) }
```

In your current case though, Rails will handle the nil for you so there is no need for the `or`

```rb
scope :valid_type, -> { where(modeltype: [nil, 36, 38]) }
```